I am trying to create blueprint for sliding images but I am not getting
[Blueprint] (https://i.sstatic.net/GPoxaNRQ.png)
Here I'm attaching the blueprint logic.
I am getting this error:

Blueprint Runtime Error: "Accessed None trying to read property Dynamicmaterialinstance". Node:  Set Scalar Parameter Value Graph:  EventGraph Function:  Execute Ubergraph BP Slideshow Blueprint:  BP_slideshow

enter image description here
I tried multiple times but ended up on same page.

Accroding to the script in the image provided, your node "Create Dynamic Material Instance" is not connected to "SET" node, thus it is never executed. Connect white trianges between those nodes, also follow where execution starts, the execution flow must be connected with thick white connections (can't say if everything is okay, because screenshot is cropped).
